# Extending Python's datetime class with type hints

Tags: python, inheritance, python-datetime

I'm on extending Python's `datetime` class from the `datetime` packages. Copying the method headers using `PyCharm` in order to support type hinting fails; the interpeter says that the `module 'datetime' has no attribute '_Text'`.

```py
import datetime as _datetime

class datetime(_datetime.datetime):
    def strptime(cls, date_string: _datetime._Text, format: _datetime._Text):
        # do some cool stuff
        return _datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime, format)
```

How can I override Python's methods without removing the "suggested" types from the official files?

Comment: Where do you think `_Text` coming from? The `datetime` module has neither a `Text` nor a `_Text` attribute.

Comment: `datetime.pyi:274`: `def strptime(cls, date_string: _Text, format: _Text) -> datetime: ...`

Comment: That doesn't mean `datetime._Text` is defined.

Comment: Also look into the section regarding [Stub Files in PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files)

Comment: FWIW, `_Text` is defined earlier on in [`datetime.pyi`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/datetime.pyi) as `str` for Python 3+